# Init class of any type (Generic function)

Tags: swift, class, type-inference

I'm pounding my head here...  i want to do something like this...

```
func serialize(into object: Any) -> [Object]{
    var temp = [Object]()
    if object is Project{
        temp = [Project]()
        for (_,j): (String,JSON) in self {
            temp.append(Project(json: j))
        }
    }
    if object is Evaluation{
        temp = [Evaluation]()
        for (_,j): (String,JSON) in self {
            temp.append(Evaluation(json: j))
        }
    }
    return temp
}
```

While this compiles, it does not return any values. None of the `if object is ...` are being satisfied .  I have tried variations of what i understand to be generics? But i don't fully understand them.

```
func serialize<T>(into object: T.Type) -> (T){ }
```

I would like to be able to use this extension to `init` the specific class that has called it and return. All the classes i'm trying to use are inherited by the realm `Object` class.  I am currently calling this function like this (it's an extension obviously)

```
let projects = json["projectList"].serialize(into: Project.self) as! [Project]
```

Comment: @matt  It does not work as in "it doesn't work at all".  I thought it would be obvious what i'm trying to do...  i will edit.

Comment: @matt Edited to reflect.

Comment: @matt yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not working because you are comparing instances while you are sending types.

Can you try this?

**Swift 3**

since you are sending:

```
serialize(into: Project.self)
```

You would need to use this kind of comparison:

```
if b.isKind(of: YourSpecificCalss.self) {...}
```

This should be the way to do the comparison you want.

Answer (score 0):

You doing it not in the way it should work, look in fact you need to specify protocol which will be inherited by all your `Object` classes. It will say I can parse JSON realized by a Model. So we can make something like:

```
enum JSONError: Error {
  case couldNotParse
}

protocol JSONable {
  static func toJSON(json: JSON) throws -> Self
}

final class Project {
//  required field
}

extension Project: JSONable {
  static func toJSON(json: JSON) throws -> Project {
    //  guard required field check else { throw JSONError.couldNotParse }

    let project = Project()
    return project
  }
}
```